# PHP Date Converting Month Name To Number Automatically

Tags: php

I am using the following code to send an email which includes the date/time. For some reason the month is coming out as a number, but not 1 - 12 as one would think but 107.

My code is:

```
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/globalVariables.php');
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/mysqli_connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"newsletterlist");
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletterusers";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$subject = str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D'), '', $_POST['subject']);
$message = str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D'), '', $_POST['body']);


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Jesse Elser<jesse@example.com>' . "\r\n";

if (!$result) exit("The query did not succeded");
else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $to = $row['email'];
        $encodedTo = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($to), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $date = date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
        $date .= date("m/d/Y h:i:sa");
        $date .= " CST";
        $body ='<!DOCTYPE HTML>';
        $body .='<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-align: center; font-family: verdana;">';
        $body .='<div id="container" style="width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; background-color: #121212;">';
        $body .='<div id="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6400;">';
        $body .='<img src="http://example.com/images/main/logo.png" width="100%">';
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="subject" style="background-color: #121212; text-align: center;">';
        $body .='<h1 style="color: #ff6400; margin: 0;">'.$subject.'</h1>';
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="message" style="background-color: #232323; color: #fff; padding: 10px;">';
        $body .=  $message;
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='<div id="footer" style="background-color: #121212; padding: 10px;">';
        $body .='<a href="http://example.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff6400;">Visit Our Site</a> | Thanks for subscribing to our newsletter! | <a href="http://example.com/scripts/php/unsubscribe.php?id='.$encodedTo.'" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff6400;">Unsubscribe</a> <br> E-mail sent: ';
        $body .= $date;
        $body .='</div>';
        $body .='</body>';
        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location: http://example.com/newsletter.php');
```

In one of my test emails the date comes out as `107/24/2015 07:20:29pm CST` when it should have been `07/24/2015 07:20:29pm CST`

Comment: I would suggest dropping a marker (such as `|`) around the date section to ensure that it is indeed coming from the date - and not somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I put a `|` on each side of my date and it is in between them so it is the date for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of concatenating bool with date string. Just look at your code at those lines:

```
$date = date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$date .= date("m/d/Y h:i:sa");
```

The **date_default_timezone_set** function returns **TRUE** or **FALSE**. And true is represented by one in this case.

Just change your code to:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
$date = date("m/d/Y h:i:sa");
```

and it should work fine.